# Unity Android Immersive mode leaving a black bar in the soft key area?

Tags: unity, android

The black bar is not hiding anything. Everything is drawn above it. But the black bar is there in place of the soft keys even when they are hidden.
I don't know how to hide it and render using whole screen.
The bar is only visible with device having soft keys not for device with physical keys.
 I have set the *Screen.fullScreen = true*.

*Unity 2018.3.4f1*

Comment: Does your app support being resized? What happens if you "split screen" your app and force it to have a different size?

Comment: I don't know much about Android Development. But the immersive mode where the device fills the whole screen is already added in unity and it is working but leaving a black bar in place of soft keys instead of filling the area

Comment: Does your device support split screen? Try putting it on split screen while its running. Based on the result, a different solution may be needed.

Comment: @TomTsagk Yes it supports split screen and the bar is not visible when in split screen. What should I do?